# What may be the issue to access any DOM button to apply with addEventListener event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am adding an event listener(in IIFE) to a key in Javascript by accessing a button from html source code through ID, but it is showing an error with message of:

> "can't read property of addeventlistener of null element;

```js
var controller = (function() {
  document.querySelector('btn2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('hello');
  });
})();
```

```html
<button id="btn2" value="value1"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></div>
```

Comment: [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): _"Parameters: A DOMString containing one or more selectors to match. This string must be a valid CSS selector string;"_

Comment: No shame in using document.getElementById if that is what you are doing. Then your code would work. Otherwise you need to add a # to the ID in the selector. Also no need to store the undefined result of an IIFE. EITHER remove the ()() around the function and call controller() when needed, OR remove `var controller =`.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_

Answer (score 0):

If you use the querySelector, you need to tell what the selector should be, for example, you want to select the element using id, you need to add '#'.

`document.querySelector('#id');`

Comment: This is a typo-type question and does not need to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You're using document.querySelector to get an element by ID, to do this, you need to add a `#` before the ID. `document.querySelector('btn2')` --> `document.querySelector('#btn2')`. I'd recommend you replace `document.querySelector` with `document.getElementById` as it's faster and it is what you should be using.

```js
var controller=(function()
{

   document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click',function()
   {
      console.log('hello');
   });
})();
```

```html
<button id="btn2" value="value1" ><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></div>
```

Comment: Why do you store the undefined result of an IIFE? Anyway, this is a typo-type question and does not need to be answered.